# Which video codecs support file level concatenation and have good resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to concatenate two videos in the fastest possible way.

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg/11175851#11175851) , ffmpeg concat protocol is extremely fast but only works with

> formats that support file level concatenation (MPEG-1, MPEG-2
>   PS, DV).

Is there any more modern codec that would allow concat protocol without re encoding ?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files)? You can losslesly transcode mp4 container to transport streams and use concat protocol. Codecs supported in mp4 include h264. Also, why would not want to use the demuxer?

Comment: I need to concatenate two videos in the fastest possible way. If I transcode i lose lot's of time. I need file-level concatenation

Comment: You can stream copy without re-encoding with demuxer. See [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).